# unable to retrieve data from sharedpreferences android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Putting data to sharedpreferences:

```
phone = binding.realOtp.getText().toString().trim();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
myEdit.putString("phone", phone);
myEdit.apply();
```

Retrieving data from sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
String y = sharedPreferences.getString("phone",null);
```

Comment: Could you also add the scenario you trying to save and retrieve the values and show some more code?

Comment: im putting and retrieving data in different activity.

Comment: May be you can try `commit` instead of `apply` but other than that I don't see any problem. I guess you need to show how are you doing that inside the activites.